# civiDiscount 3.5 and civiCRM 5.4.0

Tags: cividiscount

After upgrading to civiCRM 5.4.0, I cannot access latest version of civiDiscount via the civiCRM menu.

I see the option under Administer and Contributions, but when I click civiDiscount, I am returned to the civi Dashboard, instead of seeing the civiCRM interface.

There's no error logged by civiCRM.

I'm also running Joomla 3.8.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try to clean CiviCRM cache and do a menu rebuild?  You can do this by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update paths. Once you on the page click on Cleanup cache button.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick response! That resolved the issue :-)